# Doctrine2 querystring query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-string

Currently i develop an rest-api-app with symfony2 and doctrine2. My API should has the functionality to filter the results by an querystring.
For example, the following url:
`http://example.com/api/users?orderBy=username%20DESC&limit=20`

I can parse the querystring with `parse_str($this->getRequest()->getQueryString(), $queryString);` to an assoc array.
Is there any function that i can commit the array and doctrine selects the corresponding results? Something like `$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findByQueryString($queryString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AdrienBrault said don't use `parse_str` instead put this in your controller:

```
$orderBy = $this->get('request')->query->get('orderBy');
$limit = $this->get('request')->query->get('limit');
$rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
$users = $rep->findLimitOrderBy($orderBy, $limit);
```

And inside your user repository class:

```
public function findLimitOrderBy($orderBy, $limit)
{
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('
    SELECT u FROM UserBundle:User u
    ORDER BY u.'.$orderBy
    )
    ->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `parse_str` to access the query string parameters.

You can access the ParametersBag with `$request->query`. You could get an array with `$request->query->all()`.

You can use the `findBy` method of the repository, that accepts an array with the following format:

```
array(
    'field' => 'value',
    'field2' => 'value2',
)
```

So you could do

```
$users = $userRepository->findBy($request->query->all());
```

But it won't support the `orderBy` parameter.